# Inserción múltiple con AUTOINCREMENT desde un SELECT en SqLite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Quiero insertar todos los registros de una tabla a otra con una sola instrucción.

Mi problema es que que la tabla destino tienen una columna **`AUTOINCREMENT`** y no se como insertar el dato **NULL** en la posición (¿?) de la columna `AUTOINCREMENT`

```py
import sqlite3

conexion  = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Samuel/Desktop/Ensallos/SQLITE3/Base.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()

#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE TablaUno (Codigo VARCHAR(20),Nombre VARCHAR(20),Apellido VARCHAR(20))")
#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE TablaDos (Contador  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Nombre VARCHAR(20),Apellido VARCHAR(20))")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TablaDos SELECT ¿?,Nombre,Apellido FROM TablaUno")

conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instruccion `insert` admite que aclares que campos vas a agregar.

El campo autoincrement, no necesita recibir nada, ya que se completa automaticamente.

Por lo tanto, lo unico que necesitas es reescribir tu query, aclarando los campos que vas a llenar.

```
INSERT INTO TablaDos (Campo1, campo2, etc) SELECT Nombre,Apellido, Etc FROM TablaUno
```

Comment: Gracias, me has dado la respuesta.